# How to restrict Leaflet points to general DB rule

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am trying to make a REST call which accepts bounding box lat-lng as body parameters. But unfortunately DB geoPoint restriction is:

```
•         Latitude : max/min +90 to -90
•         Longitude : max/min +180 to -180
```

But Leaflet fetches beyond this limitation. Because of this REST call fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: Longitude outside the range of -180,180 is both valid and sometimes necessary. If you need to enforce this restriction, you'll need to clip, translate, and append to the other side of the globe to preserve topology.

Answer (score 1):

I missed it somehow, leaflet itself provides `wrapLatLng` which can be used as `this.map.wrapLatLng(latLngPoint)`, this returns normalized form of latitude longitude how we need.